# Cannot Resolve import android.support.multidex.MultiDex after change to newest Multidex

Tags: android, android-multidex

I want to use multidex in my application, At First I used depedencies :
`'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'`, but after compile this error appeared :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>
> > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/BuildConfig.class

then I changed `'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'` to `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`, but after that `import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;` in application class cannot be resolved, anybody can help ?

Answer (score 5):

Add this into your build.gradile

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Also add this into your manifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
       <application
           ...
           android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
           ...
       </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I have already put all of that code from first, but in my application class import android.support.multidex.MultiDex; can't be resolved.

Comment: Still getting the `unresolved` error in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: After following above steps, add below thing in the class which extends Application protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
 {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
 }

Answer (score 0):

You Need change

`import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;`

to

`import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency in you app gradle

```
 implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```